# send JSON with POST to Restful web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rest, asihttprequest

i want to send JSON with POST/PUT i don't know if it's the same think . 
This is the json .
{"author":"mehdi","email":"email@hotmail.fr","message":"Hello2"}
this is my wadl .

```
<resource path="/messages/"><method id="get" name="GET"><request><param name="start" style="query" type="xs:int" default="0"/><param name="max" style="query" type="xs:int" default="10"/><param name="expandLevel" style="query" type="xs:int" default="1"/><param name="query" style="query" type="xs:string" default="SELECT e FROM Message e"/></request><response><representation mediaType="application/xml"/><representation mediaType="application/json"/></response></method><method id="post" name="POST"><request><representation mediaType="application/xml"/><representation mediaType="application/json"/></request><response><representation mediaType="*/*"/></response></method><resource path="{keyid}/"><param name="keyid" style="template" type="xs:int"/><method id="get" name="GET"><request><param name="expandLevel" style="query" type="xs:int" default="1"/></request><response><representation mediaType="application/json"/></response></method></resource></resource>
```

When i trie to post with netbeans "Test restful webservice " it work and this is wat the http monitor show

> Status: 201 (Created)
>
> Time-Stamp: Sat, 21 May 2011 20:30:33
>   GMT
>
> Sent:
>   {"author":"mehdi","email":"email@hotmail.fr","message":"Hello2"}
>
> Received:
>
> ---
>
> Request: POST
>   http://localhost:8080/TRESTful/resources/messages/?
>   timestamp=1306009225785
>
> Status: 201 (Created)
>
> Time-Stamp: Sat, 21 May 2011 20:20:25
>   GMT
>
> Sent:
>   {"author":"mehdi","email":"email@hotmail.fr","message":"Hello2"}

But now i dont know how it with ASIHttpRequest .first should i make [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"]; ? and  should i send all the json like a string , or put each value with hey key , like this :

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"author"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue:@"Hello2" message:@"author"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

or should i put the JSON string in one value ?

Help please .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to send a json you have two options:

a) Send it in a file
  -Use this if you have a lot of data in a json and you may want to store it on the server for later parsing.

b) Send it as string in one value
  -Use this if your json is short and you want to parse it immediately

**EDIT**

c) Send it as seperate values if you want to skip parsing on the server and access data directly. This should be used if there is few data.